# MySQL Trigger on 2 different database server

Tags: mysql, server, triggers

I have two Mysql database server on two different host addresses. Say SERVER1 and SERVER2

How to write trigger on table from SERVER1 database and insert/update/delete record in SERVER2 table and vice versa?

Comment: Imagine what would happen if you inserted to server1 when which fired a trigger on server 1 which caused a trigger to fire on server2 which caused a trigger to fire on server 1 etc...

Comment: You should perhaps research bidirectional replication

Comment: Use remote table on [FEDERATED Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html).